# Salvar arquivo .html dinamicamente com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando um editor de código (JavaScript e HTML com `iframe`) em que preciso salvar um arquivo `.html` dinamicamente com JavaScript. Como posso fazer isso?

```
<HTML> <HEAD> 

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function escreverArquivo() {  

var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:Teste.txt", true); 

fh.WriteLine("Coloque todo o conteudo que voce deseja nesse trecho...");

fh.Close(); 

}

</SCRIPT></HEAD>
<BODY>

<P><SCRIPT language="JavaScript">  escreverArquivo(); </SCRIPT></P>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Achei esse código, mas ele aparenta só salvar `.txt`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Até onde sei, Javascript, rodando em navegador, não tem permissão para escrever arquivos na disco rígido automaticamente. É possível criar um arquivo HTML, e baixa-la na pagina. Recomendo dar uma olhada nessa pergunta, que possui um ótimo exemplo onde o usuário faz isso. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server

Comment: A API `ActiveXObject` está [obsoleta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject) e, por isso, não deveria ser utilizada. Além disso, conforme mencionou o comentário anterior, JS (em ambiente de _browser_) não tem permissão para gerenciar o sistema de arquivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resposta publicada pelo autor da pergunta em local equivocado.

para quem veio pela solução:

```
var textToSave1 = document.getElementById("código").value;
                var textToSaveAsBlob1 = new Blob([textToSave1], {type:"text/plain"});
                var textToSaveAsURL1 = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob1);
                var fileNameToSaveAs = "olamundo.html";//qualquer arquivo
                var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
                downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
                downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL1;
                downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
                downloadLink.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
            }
function destroyClickedElement(event){
            }
```

- só vai precisar mudar algumas coisas(id e nome)